# Assigning a field value by passing its name

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, field

Ive been reading the other examples of this and by I can seem to assign the value of my fields by passing in its name.

```
private string fieldName;  //contains the name of the field I want to edit

void IObserver.Update(object data)
{       
    FieldInfo field = this.GetType().GetField(fieldName);

    if(field != null)
    {
        field.SetValue(this, data);         
    }   
}
```

field always ends up null and I cant figure out why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Get*` methods in .Net reflection will only search public members by default.
To get a private field, pass `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance`.